# Timer is stopped but apparently cannot end the callback loop

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have this timer to read the textbox value every 1 sec. Once system read the value, timer supposedly stops and change label value. After leaving that timer, it should go on to process my other logics. But apparently it stuck in the loop in the timer_tick.

I tried to trace the issue with breakpoint. Notice that after program hit return; , it went to a callback function and stuck in the loop.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (m_blnReset)
    {
     this.PickNoteTimer();
    }

    //other logics
 }

 private void PickNoteTimer()
 {
    this.ReadPickNoteTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 1000 };
    this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(PickNoteTimer_Tick);
    this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Start();
 }

 private void PickNoteTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxPicknoteNumber.Text))
    {
      this.m_Picknote = txtBoxPicknoteNumber.Text.ToString();
      this.GetPickNoteDetails();

      if (this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Enabled)
         this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Stop();
      else
         return;
    }
}

private void GetPickNoteDetails()
{
   this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Stop();

   //logics to update value on label

 }
}
```

Comment: Events are not necessarily handled when they are raised. If you pause the code in the debugger before the call to `Stop` then more events may be being raised and queued, so they will be handled later whether you stop the `Timer` or not. You should call `Stop` on the `Timer` as the very first thing in the event handler, and not set any breakpoints until after that. In your case, you might want it first thing inside the first `if` block.

Comment: Apparently there's no loop in the timer_tick, where did it stuck?

Comment: @shingo, I assume that the OP meant that the event handler was executed repeatedly, which would suggest that the events had been raised but not handled before the `Timer` was stopped.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The interval is 1s, which is enough to stop before the next tick. I suspect the expression is not accurate. Even if the timer isn't stopped, I won't feel it is stuck through this code. My doubt is what makes the OP think it's **apparently** stuck.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes you are right. It went to the timer callback loop

Comment: I placed my breakpoint at the line where other logics starts, which is after the timer.

Comment: `//other logics` will definitely run before `PickNoteTimer_Tick`. It is after the timer builds, not after the timer runs.

Comment: @shingo yes it hit the breakpoint but the timer has not started yet. I let it continue to run, assuming it will hit the breakpoint again after the timer ended but it did not

Comment: It is not clear what "stuck in the loop" means. Do you mean the timer does not stop? i.e. the label is updated multiple times? Are you sure you only create one timer? If you call `PickNoteTimer()` multiple times you may have a timer that is never stopped. I would recommend inserting trace-points at significant places, i.e. where the timer is started and stopped. They have less effect on timing than breakpoints. You can also use "Make Object Id" to check that object instances are the same.

Comment: No, the timer has started yet by calling `this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Start();`. The breakpoint won't hit again, because it's not in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that you are stopping the timer in both the `PickNoteTimer_Tick` method and the `GetPickNoteDetails` method. You should remove the `this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Stop();` call from the `GetPickNoteDetails` method because it's not needed there. The timer should be stopped in the `PickNoteTimer_Tick` method when the condition `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxPicknoteNumber.Text))` is met.

Here's the updated code:

```
private void PickNoteTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxPicknoteNumber.Text))
    {
        this.m_Picknote = txtBoxPicknoteNumber.Text;
        this.GetPickNoteDetails();

        if (this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Enabled)
            this.ReadPickNoteTimer.Stop();
    }
}

private void GetPickNoteDetails()
{
    // Logics to update value on label
    // You don't need to stop the timer here
}
```

If you are still facing issues with the timer getting stuck, there might be some other factors in your application that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Hi. I tried changing the stop() into the  PickNoteTimer_Tick method and removed the stop() in GetPickNoteDetails(). I extracted the codes and debug it in a new project, with only one breakpoint in Form1_Load() after the timer. It still went to a loop.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to move the timer creation code to your constructor:

```
private readonly Timer readPickNoteTimer ;
public MyForm(){

    InitializeComponents();
    this.readPickNoteTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 1000 };
    this.readPickNoteTimer.Tick += PickNoteTimer_Tick;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (m_blnReset)
    {
        this.readPickNoteTimer .Start();
    }
}
```

Having a method that creates the timer suggest that maybe the method is called multiple times. And this could result in multiple timer objects, this would mean the first created timer is no longer referred, and can no longer be stopped.

In theory the timer should have a finalizer that stops it eventually, once it is no longer referred, but the finalizer can take an arbitrary long time before it is run. It is also possible it makes some global registration that prevents collection. I'm not sure about the exact behavior.

Ensuring that only one timer object is created should avoid at this possible issue. And you can still start and stop the timer multiple times if you want. And even if it does not solve the issue it is probably good practice anyway.

Comment: Hi I have tried your method, but the timer still did not stop. I used a count after the stop() in tick() and used tracepoint on the count. The count only hit once. So there is only one counter is created and it is remained stuck in the timer callback

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: Sometimes when an attempted solution causes problems of its own, it's worth taking a moment to ask if this is the right approach in the first place. This is a concept known as an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Having experienced this same kind of issue myself many times, I have settled on an way of doing a "timed update" that doesn't rely on a timer to make the time intervals, but uses a `Task.Delay` to do the same thing with less fuss and bother. This is an alternative approach you might try:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        numericUpDown.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            textBoxTitle.Clear();
            textBoxText.Clear(); 
        };
        _ = execTimerLoop();
    }

    private async Task execTimerLoop()
    {
        Cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
        do
        {
            // Update title bar ~ every second or so
            Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss tt");

            getPickNoteDetails();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        } while (!Cancel.IsCancellationRequested);
    }

    CancellationTokenSource? Cancel { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

**Example**

This routine polls the controls on the left ~ once per second, and also updates the Title Bar text with the current time.

[image: screenshot]

```
    private void getPickNoteDetails()
    {
        var selectionFontB4 = richTextBox.Font;
        var selectionColorB4 = richTextBox.SelectionColor;
        richTextBox.Clear();

        richTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(selectionFontB4.FontFamily, 14F, FontStyle.Bold);
        richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(0x22, 0x22, 0x22);
        richTextBox.AppendText($"{numericUpDown.Value}");

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxTitle.Text) ) 
        {
            richTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(selectionFontB4.FontFamily, 12F, FontStyle.Bold);
            richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.CadetBlue;
            richTextBox.AppendText($" : {textBoxTitle.Text.ToUpper()}");
            richTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        richTextBox.SelectionFont = selectionFontB4;
        richTextBox.SelectionColor = selectionColorB4;
        richTextBox.AppendText($"{textBoxText.Text}");
        richTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```